# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}dx $ using high school techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Is there a way to compute this integral,  $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}dx =\ln({k+1})$$ without using the derivation under the integral sign nor transforming it to a double integral and then interchanging the order of integration. High school techniques only if possible.

Comment: Your integral expression above is wrong, simply try $k=0$. It should be $\int_0^1 \frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}dx =\ln(k+1)$

Comment: Thank you Pauly, I have corrected it.

Comment: I think there's a way to do this by writing a double integral. With one order of the integral signs, we get the LHS (left hand side) of your post; with another order, we get the RHS. Fubini then tells us that these must be equal.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, That is exactly what Idris refuses to accept.

Comment: Anything is a high school technique if you have the right attitude! Except for Iwasawa theory. Definitely not Iwasawa theory.

Comment: Here's the problem:  I don't like the way in which it is **demanded** that answers must adhere to a subjective "high school" rule; that this rule is not **explained**, and then **on top of** it all, the fact that the individual asking has not shown any original effort, instead in effect saying "DO THIS FOR ME."  Vote to close.

Comment: The question is not written in antagonistic way, so the sense that it "demands" something seems out of line. Yes, it asks if a problem can be solved without using certain methods, and why is that so terrible? It is not unreasonable to ask if a problem understandable at a certain level can also be solved at that level, e.g., the Gaussian integral evaluation from probability without using a double integral or methods of complex analysis, as the result itself can be appreciated before someone knows such techniques. In summary, I disagree that this question deserves to be closed.

Comment: @heropup, My question is not of the format: DO THIS FOR ME, but instead of the Format: ''Please, if you know another way than that i previously know, so please let me know it.'' I am very sorry if I do not asked it as it should be. The final goal is to give help to any one who will be interested in this integral in the futur. Not only me.

Comment: @Integrator, thank you for telling me that there exists something which is ''accepting a response''in this site. It was not known to me, so i will go back to accept one answer for every one of my questions. THe problem is when there are at least two different and excellent answers ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a *seemingly* elementary solution: Using the following simple limit

$$ \ln x = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x^{h} - 1}{h} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^{1/n} - 1}{1/n}, $$

it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k} - 1}{\log x} \, dx
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k} - 1}{n (x^{1/n} - 1)} \, dx \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(y^{nk} - 1)y^{n-1}}{y - 1} \, dy, \quad (\text{substitute } x = y^{n}) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} (1+y+\cdots +y^{nk-1})y^{n-1} \, dy.
\end{align*}

Now using the following simple formula

$$ \int_{0}^{1} y^{i-1} \, dy = \frac{1}{i}, $$

we get the following identity

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k} - 1}{\log x} \, dx
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{nk+n-1} \right) 
 =\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{nk-1} \frac{1}{n+i}.
\end{align*}

Modifying the summand a little bit, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k} - 1}{\log x} \, dx
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{nk-1} \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{1+(i/n)}
 = \int_{0}^{k} \frac{dt}{1+t}
 = \ln(k+1).
\end{align*}

P.s. All these steps are elementary except for one point. Can you figure out where it is?

---

**EDIT.** Elementary solution is not always the easiest solution as the essence is often shadowed by the technical intricacy involved. Nevertheless, here is a solution which uses only freshman-level calculus:

I will assume that $k$ is a positive integer (as I implicitly did in the first solution). Now let $n$ be another positive integer. Then by the substitution $x = y^{n}$ we get

$$ I := \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{k} - 1}{\log x} \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(y^{nk} - 1)y^{n-1}}{\log y} \, dy. $$

For the solution, we claim the following:

> **Claim.** For $0 < y < 1$ we have $y \leq \frac{y-1}{\log y} \leq 1$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $f(y) = y \log y + 1 - y$ and $g(y) = y - 1 - \log y$. By differentiating once, we have
>   $$ f'(y) = \log y \leq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad g'(y) = 1 - y^{-1} \leq 0.$$
>   This shows that both $f$ and $g$ are decreasing on $(0, 1]$. Since $f(1) = 0$ and $g(1) = 0$, we get both
>   $$ f(y) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad g(y) \geq 0 \quad \text{for} \quad 0 < y < 1. $$
>   The claim follows from these two inequalities. ////

Now write $I$ in the following form:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1 - y^{nk})y^{n-1}}{1 - y} \frac{y - 1}{\log y} \, dy. $$

Then by the claim we obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1 - y^{nk})y^{n}}{1 - y} \, dy \leq I \leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1 - y^{nk})y^{n-1}}{1 - y} \, dy. $$

We know how to calculate both integrals and where they converge as $n \to \infty$ from the previous answer:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1 - y^{nk})y^{n}}{1 - y} \, dy
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1 - y^{nk})y^{n-1}}{1 - y} \, dy
= \log(k+1). $$

Therefore the conclusion follows from the Squeezing Theorem.

Comment: Maybe interchanging the integral and limit.

Comment: @IdrisAddou Even my answer involves swapping the limit (of the infinite summation) and the integral. At the end of the day, all the "different" techniques relies on carefully and judiciously swapping two different limits.

Comment: @sos440: You used this matter: 
$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}f_{n}(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx$ which is allowed
under somme restriction as uniform convergence of the function sequence on
the compact [0,1]. I think this is not a high school technique. Any way, i
find it nice.          Bay the way it is in essence the same way as that using double
integral and then Fubini's thm.

Comment: IdrisAddou, asking for solutions that include justification of analytic manipulations like swapping the order of summation or integration is going beyond the pre-university level. The posted solution using differentiation under the integral sign includes no justification for why that method fits this application, and to do so would go beyond the level of high school. To some extent a certain amount of "handwaving" in the derivations should be allowable at the level at which you are asking the question.

Comment: @Idris That is exactly what I pointed out in my PS. In this case even uniform convergence fails, so we need the dominated convergence theorem. Thankfully, there is a way to circumvent this problem by using solely calculus techniques as I demonstrated in the edited version, but I do not think these solutions reveal the nature of our integral.

Comment: Correction: the integrand in my first solution *does* converge uniformly as $n \to \infty$. What I meant was that $1/(n(x^{1/n} - 1))$ does not converge uniformly as $n \to \infty$, but thanks to the factor $x^{k} - 1$ we indeed obtain the uniform convergence of $(x^{k} - 1)/(n(x^{1/n} - 1))$.

Comment: @sos440, your last solution using squeez thm is of a maestro! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^k-1}{\log(x)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(k+1)x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-(k+1)x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-(k+1)x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{(k+1)\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^{(k+1)\epsilon}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_1^{k+1}\frac{e^{-\epsilon x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x\tag{6}\\
&=\int_1^{k+1}\frac1x\mathrm{d}x-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_1^{k+1}\frac{1-e^{-\epsilon x}}x\mathrm{d}x\tag{7}\\
&=\int_1^{k+1}\frac1x\mathrm{d}x\tag{8}\\[10pt]
&=\log(k+1)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto e^{-x}$
$(2)$: express as a limit so that we can separate the integrals
$(3)$: separate the integrals
$(4)$: substitute $x\mapsto x/(k+1)$
$(5)$: recombine integrals
$(6)$: substitute $x\mapsto\epsilon x$
$(7)$: separate the significant from the rest
$(8)$: Squeeze Theorem: $1-\epsilon x\le e^{-\large\epsilon x}\le1\implies0\le\int_1^{k+1}\frac{1-e^{-\large\epsilon x}}x\mathrm{d}x\le\epsilon k$
$(9)$: integrate

Answer (score 9):

Note that $x^k = e^{k \ln(x)}$. Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln(x)} = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{k^l \ln^{l-1}(x)}{l!}$$
Hence, our integral becomes
$$\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{k^l}{l!} \int_0^1 \ln^{l-1}(x)dx = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{k^l}{l!} \int_0^1 \ln^{l-1}(x)dx = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{l-1}\dfrac{k^l}l = \ln(1+k)$$
since $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \ln^{l-1}(x)dx = \int_{\infty}^0 (-t)^{l-1} e^{-t} (-dt)= (-1)^{l-1}\int_0^{\infty} t^{l-1}e^{-t} dt = (-1)^{l-1} (l-1)!$$

---

As pointed out in the comments, this is true for $-1<k\leq 1$. For $k> 1$, the proof can be easily extended. Set $$I(k) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^k-1}{\ln(x)}dx$$
We then have
\begin{align}
I(k) - I(k-1) & = \int_0^1 x^{k-1}\dfrac{(x-1)}{\ln(x)}dx = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{k-1} \ln^{l-1}(x)}{l!}dx\\
& = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}(-1)^l \dfrac{(1/k)^l}l = \ln(1+1/k) \text{ (since $1/k<1$)}
\end{align}
This now gives us $I(k) = \ln(1+k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: Very nice calculation, thanks!!!

Comment: This derivation is only valid for $-1 < k < 1$, and perhaps also at $k = 1$ if you are careful, but the result itself is true for all $k > -1$. So this is not a complete explanation. To be fair, though, the original question was vague about the range of $k$ for which the equality was desired.

Comment: @KCd Hopefully fixed now for all $k>-1$.

Comment: Of course, swapping the infinite summation and the integral may be considered as non-high school stuff (depending on the high school you study).

Answer (score 7):

> I'm not expecting any upvote for this but surely this answer could also help someone!.

Let
$$I(k)=\int_0^1{\frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}dx}$$

$$I'(k)=\int_0^1{\frac{(x)^k\ln x}{\ln x}dx}=\int_0^1{x^kdx}=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$I(k)=\ln(k+1)+C$$

Since we have $I(0)=0\implies \ln(1)+C=0\implies C=0$

> $$I(k)=\int_0^1{\frac{x^k-1}{\ln x}dx}=\ln(k+1)$$

Comment: This is a great proof but not a very good answer. OP explicitly asks for a proof without this technique.

Comment: FYI, the "Leibniz Integral Rule" is precisely the method of differentiation under the integral sign, which was explicitly disallowed in the question.

Comment: Hi there, thanks all of you for your interests in my question. I asked to do not use Leibniz rule nor Fubini's technic and I precise now to also do not use the change of variable  $x=e^{-y}$ which convert the problem to the Frullani's integral. The raison is that all these ways to do are previously used in this site, so I asked new way! The way by Adhvaitha is new for me even if some restrictions are needed as KCd reported. Thanks for all.

Comment: @Integrator: IdrisAddou explained that the interest was in seeing a *new* way to solve the problem, where "new" means not previously known to the OP. I had already seen the power series method of Adhvaitha before, but evidently IdrisAddou had not, so it counts as new.

Comment: @Integrator thanks for letting us know that what could be another and easy way to solve the integral in question.

Comment: @Integrator: why change from one "forbidden" method to another? If the idea is to present alternate methods of computation, then why not leave the previous approach as well? Although differentiating inside the integral, the current approach is simpler than the previous one.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another answer.
It is easy to see that $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x^k-1}{\log x}$, with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=k$ is a continuous fonction on $[0,1]$ for $k> 0$. Put now for $0<h<1$ $\displaystyle F(h)=\int_0^h f(t)dt$. We have $F(h)\to F(1)=I_k$ if $h\to 0$, $h<1$.
But:
$$F(h)=\int_0^{h}\frac{x^k}{\log x}dx-\int_0^h \frac{dx}{\log x}=\int_{h^{k+1}}^h \frac{-dx}{\log x}$$
By the change of variable $t^{k+1}=u$ in the first integral.

Now for $x\in [h^{k+1},h]$ we have
$$h^{k+1}\frac{-1}{x\log x}\leq \frac{-x}{x\log x}\leq h\frac{-1}{x\log x}$$
where we have used that $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{x\log x}\geq 0$.

As $h^{k+1}\leq h$, integrating we get:
$$h^{k+1}\int_{h^{k+1}}^h \frac{-1}{x\log x}dx\leq F(h)\leq h\int_{h^{k+1}}^h\frac{-1}{x\log x}dx$$
Hence
$$h^{k+1}\log(k+1)\leq F(h)\leq h\log(k+1)$$
and if $h\to 1$, we get the result.

Comment: Nice work! (+1) This solution is elementary yet loses no intuition.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{k} - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x =\ln\pars{k + 1}:\
>      {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{k} - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
=-\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{k} - 1}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{-\,{1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}}}\ \,\dd x\ =\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{k + t} - x^{t}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over t + 1} - {1 \over t + k + 1}}\,\dd t
=\left.\ln\pars{t + 1 \over t + k + 1}\right\vert_{\, t\ =\ 0}^{\, t\ \to\ \infty}
=-\ln\pars{1 \over k + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{k + 1}}
\end{align}